# Flyway boolean bit schema version and validate issue

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, postgresql-9.4, flyway

I use flyway 4.0, hibernate 5.1.0.Final and 2 databases : postgresql 9.4.1208 and hsqldb 2.3.1 (for test)

We need to supervise database status of our application. I create a SchemaVersionEntity to check database (version of script and status success of last script) entity column success is of type Boolean

We do jpa validation:
in flyway postgresql createMetaDataTable success is map to boolean : https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/resources/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/postgresql/createMetaDataTable.sql

in flyway hsql createMetaDataTable success is map to bit : (boolean exists since v2) https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/resources/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/hsql/createMetaDataTable.sql

So I get a error:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [success] in table [schema_version]; found [bit (Types#BIT)], but expecting [boolean (Types#BOOLEAN)]

What is the best solution ?
Modify  flyway\flyway-core\src\main\resources\org\flywaydb\core\internal\dbsupport\hsql ?

```
  "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can customize H2Dialect and use it in Test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize H2Dialect and use it in Test Configuration

```
public class CustomH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {

    public CustomH2Dialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "bit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have already tried it, but this means that every bit should be mapped to boolean. Do you know how to declare the column type only to one column of one table?